# i'm not getting a response from volley

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-volley, android-api-levels

i'm trying to build a weather app as my first time working with and api
so i'm starting with the documentations and still not getting a response

```
fun getWeather(view:View){
        val city = cityName.text.toString()
        cityName.text.clear()
        //val  url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$city&appid=cb8d284902f295b8759aa295cb6bafc3"
        val url = "https://www.google.com"
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, Response.Listener<String> {
            response ->
            weatherResult.text = "it worked" + response.substring(0,10)
        },Response.ErrorListener {
            weatherResult.text = "there was an error"
        })
        queue.add(stringRequest)

    }
```

Comment: i have to values of "url" because i tried the first one and it gave me a error response

Comment: Use printStackTrace() to see the error and edit your question with the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be problem with your URL. I notice that api.openweathermap.org doesn't contains `https://` header in it.

Try to add **https://api.openweathermap.org/** followed by your search criteria and it should work as expected.